# How to perform time-consuming operations in the background and update the UI using coroutines in Kotlin for Android development in Jetpack Compose

Tags: multithreading, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

I'm developing an android app that is a bitcoin wallet using Jetpack Compose.

I have **Wallet.kt** file with:

```
fun sync() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Wallet is syncing")
    wallet.sync(blockchain, LogProgress)
}

fun getBalance(): ULong = wallet.getBalance().total
```

then in HomeScreen.kt I have

```
internal class WalletViewModel() : ViewModel() {
  private var _balance: MutableLiveData<ULong> = MutableLiveData(0u)
  val balance: LiveData<ULong>
      get() = _balance

  fun updateBalance() {
    Wallet.sync()
    _balance.value = Wallet.getBalance()
  }
```

then outside of this is composable function HomeScreen

```
internal fun HomeScreen(
  navController: NavController,
  walletViewModel: WalletViewModel = viewModel()
) {
   val balance by walletViewModel.balance.observeAsState()
   Image(Modifier.clickable{ walletViewModel.updateBalance() }
}
```

**My problem being** that when I click on that Image which has clickable, the whole app freezes, until the updateBalance() is completed.
I learned that this is because the **sync()** function inside Wallet.kt file is performing network task on the Main Thread and the app is in Main Thread, so the whole app has to wait until sync is done.

Can you suggest how should I implement coroutines or different way, so that the sync happens inside background thread and then updates _balance to/in the Main ?

I've tried lots of things, including suspend before sync() and async in the viewModelScope, but nothing seems to work how I want to.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it in two ways, one is to attach the async call into the `viewModelScope` and mark the async call as suspend, the other one is creating a coroutine in your repository with Context and execute it in another thread.

### Solution 1

```
fun updateBalance() {
  viewModelScope.launch {
    Wallet.sync()
    _balance.value = Wallet.getBalance()
   }
  }

suspend fun sync() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Wallet is syncing")
    wallet.sync(blockchain, LogProgress)
}
```

### Solution 2

```
suspend fun sync() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Wallet is syncing")
    withContext(Dispatcher.IO) {
      wallet.sync(blockchain, LogProgress)
   }
}
```

Comment: These don't work. The Solution 1 has redundant suspend, because it isn't doing wallet.sync(blockchain, LogProgress) inside withContext(Dispatcher.IO) {}. The Solution 2 however, the Wallet.sync() function cannot be called from inside updateBalance() because the suspend function can only be called from a coroutine or another suspend function.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is:

```
fun updateBalance() {
  viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
    Wallet.sync()
    
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
      _balance.value = Wallet.getBalance()
    }
  }
}
```

This syncs Wallet in the background thread and after it's done, it updates the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would solve this by moving to StateFlow which is thread safe instead of LiveData which always needs to be posted on the main thread. That said, the solution should be pretty straightforward:

```kotlin
fun updateBalance() {
  viewModelScope(Dispatcher.IO).launch {
    wallet.sync(blockchain, LogProgress)
    _balance.postValue(Wallet.getBalance())
  }
}
```

With State flow, it's even simpler:

```kotlin
fun updateBalance() {
  viewModelScope(Dispatcher.IO).launch {
    wallet.sync(blockchain, LogProgress)
    _balance.value = Wallet.getBalance()
  }
}
```

And you'll have to use [collectAsStateWithLifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/compose/package-summary#(kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow).collectAsStateWithLifecycle(kotlin.Any,androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle,androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle.State,kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext)) to convert the StateFlow to a Compose State object.